# Weird issue with java substring

Tags: java

Hi I have the following code:

```
String oriString = "0100002d0016012866590003";

String firstByte = oriString.substring(8, 2);
System.out.println(firstByte);
```

And it is throwing the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   String index out of range: -6     at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown
>   Source)

My string has enough characters, more than 8. But I can't do anything more than `substring(3,2)` because it throws the above exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)), the second char is the end index. This must be greater then the start index (parameter 1).
So your Statement must be

```
 String firstByte = oriString.substring(8, 10);
```

> public String substring(int beginIndex,
>                  int endIndex)
>
> Returns a new string that is a substring of this string. The substring
>   begins at the specified beginIndex and extends to the character at
>   index endIndex - 1. Thus the length of the substring is
>   endIndex-beginIndex.  Examples:
>
> "hamburger".substring(4, 8) returns "urge"  "smiles".substring(1, 5)
>   returns "mile"   Parameters:beginIndex - the beginning index,
>   inclusive.endIndex - the ending index, exclusive.Returns:the specified
>   substring.Throws:IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the beginIndex is
>   negative, or endIndex is larger than the length of this String object,
>   or beginIndex is larger than endIndex.

Answer (score 2):

Please check javadocs :)

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)

IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the beginIndex is negative, or endIndex is larger than the length of this String object, or beginIndex is larger than endIndex.

As 2<8 you are getting IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 1):

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)

The parameters are for `first index` to `end index`

So if you want to start at index 8 and get the next two chars, then you need to provide

```
String firstByte = oriString.substring(8, 10);
```

According to the javadocs its says

> IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the beginIndex is negative, or endIndex
>   is larger than the length of this String object, or beginIndex is
>   larger than endIndex.

Comment: So the end index I need to add it it ?

Comment: You need to either use `substring` with a begin only index (it will read to the end of the string) ot use from index, end index where end index should be greater than start index